# Add the edit data function in recycler view using interfaces

Tags: java, android

My code is working fine, it adds the data when refresh the page and it deletes the data on long press, but when I refresh the page duplicates the same data that was added before secondly I want to add the edit function in edit data button but I have no idea how to do this. Geeks help me to sort this issue.

**MAIN ACTIVITY:**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements ExampleInterface{
RecyclerView recyclerView;
RecyclerAdapter recyclerAdapter;

List<String> moviesList;

SwipeRefreshLayout swipeRefreshLayout;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    moviesList=new ArrayList<>();

    recyclerView= findViewById(R.id.recyclerView);
    recyclerAdapter=new RecyclerAdapter(moviesList,this);

    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));

    recyclerView.setAdapter(recyclerAdapter);

    DividerItemDecoration dividerItemDecoration=new DividerItemDecoration(this, DividerItemDecoration.VERTICAL);
    recyclerView.addItemDecoration(dividerItemDecoration);


    moviesList.add("Iron Man");
    moviesList.add("Iron men");
    moviesList.add("Iron Mann");
    moviesList.add("Iron Many");
    moviesList.add("Iron Manv");
    moviesList.add("Iron Mane");
    moviesList.add("Iron Manr");
    moviesList.add("Iron Manee");
    moviesList.add("Iron Manw");
    moviesList.add("Iron Mana");
    moviesList.add("Iron Mana");
    moviesList.add("Iron Manc");
    moviesList.add("Iron Manx");
    moviesList.add("Iron Manz");
    moviesList.add("Iron Mann");

    swipeRefreshLayout =findViewById(R.id.swiperefreshlayout);
    swipeRefreshLayout.setOnRefreshListener(new SwipeRefreshLayout.OnRefreshListener() {

        @Override
        public void onRefresh() {
            moviesList.add("Black widows(2022)");
            moviesList.add("Black widow(2022)");
            moviesList.add("Black widow(2020)");
            moviesList.add("Black widow(2019)");
            moviesList.add("Black widow(2018)");
            recyclerAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            swipeRefreshLayout.setRefreshing(false);
        }
    });



}

@Override
public void onItemClick(int position) {

    Toast.makeText(this,moviesList.get(position),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();


}

@Override
public void onLongItemClick(int position) {

    moviesList.remove(position);
    recyclerAdapter.notifyItemRemoved(position);

}
@Override
public void editData(int position){

    moviesList.remove(position);
    recyclerAdapter.notifyItemRemoved(position);

}}
```

**Adapter class:**

```
public class RecyclerAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerAdapter.viewHolder>{
private static final String TAG="RecyclerAdapter";

List<String> moviesList;
private ExampleInterface exampleInterface;

public RecyclerAdapter(List<String> moviesList,ExampleInterface exampleInterface) {
    this.moviesList = moviesList;
    this.exampleInterface=exampleInterface;
}

@NonNull
@Override



public viewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    LayoutInflater layoutInflater=LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext());
    View view=layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.row_item, parent,false);

    viewHolder viewHolder= new viewHolder(view);

    return viewHolder;
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull viewHolder holder, int position) {
holder.rowCountTextview.setText(String.valueOf(position));
holder.textView.setText(moviesList.get(position));

}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return moviesList.size();
}

class viewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{

    ImageView imageview;
    TextView textView,rowCountTextview;
    Button btn;

    public viewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
        super(itemView);

        imageview=itemView.findViewById(R.id.imageView);
        textView=itemView.findViewById(R.id.textView);
        rowCountTextview=itemView.findViewById(R.id.rowcounttextview);
        btn=itemView.findViewById(R.id.button);




        itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                exampleInterface.onItemClick(getAdapterPosition());
            }
        });


        btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

                exampleInterface.onLongItemClick(getAdapterPosition());

            }
        });




        itemView.setOnLongClickListener(new View.OnLongClickListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onLongClick(View view) {

               /* moviesList.remove(getAdapterPosition());
                notifyItemRemoved(getAdapterPosition());*/

                exampleInterface.onLongItemClick(getAdapterPosition());
                return true;


            }
        });


    }


}}
```

**INTERFACE CLASS**

```
public interface ExampleInterface {void  onItemClick( int position);

void onLongItemClick(int position);void editData(int position);}
```

**MAINACTIVITY.XML**

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto" xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent" tools:context=".MainActivity">
<androidx.swiperefreshlayout.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout
    android:id="@+id/swiperefreshlayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="1.0"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="1.0">


    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recyclerView"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" >


    </androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView>

</androidx.swiperefreshlayout.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout></androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

**ROW_ITEM.XML**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_width="90dp"
        android:layout_height="82dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:background="@color/black"
        android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_launcher_foreground" />



    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="12dp"
        android:text="TextView"
        android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Medium"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/rowcounttextview"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/imageView"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/rowcounttextview"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="TextView"
        android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Small"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/textView"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="EDIT DATA"
        android:textSize="20dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/rowcounttextview"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="1.0"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="196dp" />
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: What is the expected behavior of the refresh action?

Comment: when refreshing the page it add the 5 more items in the list

Answer (score 0):

Question 1:

The documentation is kinda unclear, but I guess using `setRefreshing(false)` is not enough.

> Notify the widget that refresh state has changed. Do not call this when refresh is triggered by a swipe gesture.

> @param refreshing Whether or not the view should show refresh progress.

So try adding `setEnabled(false)`.

Question 2:

Use the method `set(int index, String element)` of `ArrayList<String>`.

If you want to ask your user for a new string to insert there, you could use an [AlertDialog](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/android/android_alert_dialoges.htm) (*popup*) and pass an [EditText](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/EditText) to `setView`. When the user clicks the *OK-button*, you can obtain the text using `EditText#getText().toString()`.

Use `recyclerAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged()` to refresh.